# Which font does 'Academia Stack Exchange' use?

Tags: discussion, design

Does anyone know the font name?

[image]

Reference link: [Why aren't all research articles on PubMed?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/9044/why-arent-all-research-articles-on-pubmed)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to the info from celeritas, you can use http://www.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont/ to use images to find fonts in the future. Here [is an example](http://www.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont/results?ch%5B0%5D=W&ch%5B1%5D=h&ch%5B2%5D=y&ch%5B3%5D=a&ch%5B4%5D=r&ch%5B5%5D=e&ch%5B6%5D=n&ch%5B7%5D=%27&ch%5B8%5D=t&ch%5B9%5D=a&ch%5B10%5D=l&ch%5B11%5D=l&ch%5B12%5D=r&ch%5B13%5D=e&ch%5B14%5D=s&ch%5B15%5D=e&ch%5B16%5D=a&ch%5B17%5D=r&ch%5B18%5D=c&ch%5B19%5D=h&ch%5B20%5D=a&ch%5B21%5D=r&ch%5B22%5D=t&ch%5B23%5D=&ch%5B24%5D=&ch%5B25%5D=&ch%5B26%5D=&ch%5B27%5D=e&ch%5B28%5D=s&ch%5B29%5D=o&ch%5B30%5D=n&ch%5B31%5D=P&ch%5B32%5D=u&ch%5B33%5D=b&ch%5B34%5D=M&ch%5B35%5D=e&ch%5B36%5D=d&ch%5B37%5D=&ch%5B38%5D=&wtfserver=wtf_e_41&id=00204b4a535186d5000a40200000712c&glyphcount=39&imageid=0&x=88&y=35) from this font.

Answer (score 1):

This is the `font-family` defined in the main stylesheet on the Academic Stack Exchange website:

```
font-family:Consolas,Menlo,Monaco,Lucida Console,Liberation Mono,DejaVu Sans Mono,Bitstream Vera Sans Mono,Courier New,monospace,serif;
```

The `font-family` css property lists specific fonts and font styles in order of descending priority; e.g., if a certain browser can't display the first-choice font, it will try the second font in the list, etc.

Comment: do you also know the title's font size? I tested 12px 14px 16px, however the font size is a little bit different, I have Consolas installed in my PC, any idea?

Comment: Hard to give an exact answer because the font size is not set in pixels on that stylesheet; the size in pixels will depend on the resolution of your screen.

Comment: hmmm... I think that enough already to know the name, thanks

Comment: Note that this is only the monospace font; most text is obviously not monospaced.